# ¿Como puedo invertir el orden de una matriz?

Tags: java

Por ejemplo si tengo **[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]**, como hago para que me quede al contrario **[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]**

```
int n = 0, m = 0, c = 0, aux = 0;
String lista = "";
int j = 0, i = 0;

n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Escriba la cantidad de filas"));
m = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Escriba la cantidad de columnas"));

int matriz[][] = new int[n][m];

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {// llenado automatico
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        c = c + 1;
        matriz[i][j] = c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Es la misma situación solo que recorres la matriz de forma inversa, es decir inicias desde `n-1` hasta `0` y de `m-1` hasta 0

Comment: mmm gracias amigo seria algo asi:                                                                                                                for (i = n-1; i >= 0; i--) {// llenado automatico
        for (j = m-1; j >= 0; j--) {
           JOptionpane.showMessageDialog(null,matriz[i][j]);
        }
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente la recorres al revés, empiezas desde el tamaño de la matriz que son n y m -1, que vaya hasta 0 y lo decrementa por ejemplo:

n=2
m=2

i=2-1; i>=0; i--  por lo tanto i=1; i>=0; i--
j=2-1; j>=0; j--  por lo tanto j=1; j>=0; j--

```
n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Escriba la cantidad de 
    filas"));
m = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Escriba la cantidad de 
    columnas"));

int matriz[][] = new int[n][m];

for (i= n-1; i >= 0; i--) {// llenado automatico
    for (j = m-1; j >= 0; j--) {
        c = c + 1;
        matriz[i][j] = c;
    }
}
```